# PHP form with limit some value from html post

Tags: php

my html code :

```
<form action="myfile.php" method="POST">
 Data
 <select id="data" name="data" class="form-control" required>
                          <option value="data1">Data 1</option>
                          <option value="data2">Data 2</option>
                        </select>

Value
 <select id="value" name="value" class="form-control" required>
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                              <option value="3">3</option>
                          <option value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
</form>
```

This my php code :

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
$value = $_POST['value'];

if code {
} else {
HERE MY PROCCESS
}
?>
```

How if Data 1 is selected and value is must more than 3,if not it will get notice "Value of Data 1 is must more than 3" and if not error it will return to my proccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check:

```
if($data == "data1" && $value == 1) {
   // notice
} else {
   // process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($data == "data1" && $value > 3) {
   //everything is fine
} else {
   // through notice
}
```